# How to make hover full fit the border in leftside?

Tags: html, css

I've tried to make hover full, it fit the border in left side but I haven't found how to make this full. I used right-border and as the pictures you can see the hover not full in left side. could you guys help me? Thank in advance.

[No hover](http://tinypic.com/r/wtez60/8)

[With Hover](http://tinypic.com/r/6pukgy/8)

```css
     #menutext {
  float: left;
  border-bottom:1px solid #d2d6d5;
  width: 100%;
       background:gray;
  
 }
 
   #menutext ul {
   display: inline; 
   margin-left: 10%;

  
  }
  
   #menutext ul  li{
   display: inline; 
   position: relative;
   border-left: none;
  
  }
  
   #menutext li a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #444;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: MuseoSans,serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   padding:10px;
   border-right: 1px solid #d2d6d5;
   text-align: center; 
  
  }
  
   #menutext ul li :hover{
         
    color:#919191;
  background-color: #f4f4f4; 
    
         }
```

```html
    <div id="menu">
    <div id="menutext">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">product</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the background-color to change for the hovered menu item, but you are seeing gap around what's highlighted and the margins of the item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a cleaned up version of your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/austinthedeveloper/vLubg8pg/

The big changes were getting rid of display: inline on the ul and li along with setting the link as a block element:

```
#menutext {
     float: left;
     border-bottom:1px solid #d2d6d5;
     width: 100%;
     background:gray;
 }
 #menutext ul {
     margin: 0 0 0 10%;
 }
 #menutext ul li {
     float: left;
     position: relative;
     border-left: none;
     list-style: none;
 }
 #menutext li a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #444;
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-family: MuseoSans, serif;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     padding:10px;
     border-right: 1px solid #d2d6d5;
     text-align: center;
 }
 #menutext ul li :hover {
     color:#919191;
     background-color: #f4f4f4;
 }
```